# Compare original MySQL database with new locally

Tags: mysql, compare

Is there way to compare mysql db i saved in file.sql with opther original.sql on my local computer without internet connection or without setting up any kind of mysql server, just copare local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you to compare if they're different you can use the `diff` (Mac, Linux) or `comp` (Windows) command:

```
diff original.sql local.sql
```

Or

```
comp original.sql local.sql
```

If the two files are identical the tool won't return anything. If they're different then you'll see an output like

```
< some text
---
> some other text
```

You can learn more about the format of the output [here](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/diff/diff_3.html).

If you don't want to deal with command-like tools you could use something like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)

Comment: @JohnA: You'll need to do it from the command line. I have no idea of where to start that in Windows these days but you can always download a tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and let it take care of it for you.

Comment: I know how to start command line on windows yet when i type diff or comp it saying command not found...